# How to display AppArmor denied messages as desktop notifications

Tags: security, apparmor

How can I get live notifications on my desktop whenever an AppArmor denied message is triggered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done with apparmor-notify

1. Install it through `apt` (`sudo apt-get install apparmor-notify`)
2. In `/etc/apparmor/notify.conf` change the usergroup to 'adm' (all users using sudo are in this group)
3. add `aa-notify -p` to your startup applications.

You can then test it by triggering a AppArmor Denied event with

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -n -s 0 -w /foo
```